# Awk: How to cut similar part of 2 fields and then get the difference of remaining part?

Tags: csv, awk, gawk

Let say I have 2 fields displaying epoch time in microseconds:

1318044415123456,1318044415990056

What I wanted to do is:

1. Cut the common part from both fields: "1318044415"
2. Get the difference of the remaining parts: 990056 - 123456 = 866600

Why am I doing this? Because awk uses floating point IEEE 754 but not 64 bit integers and I need to get difference of epoch time of 2 events in microseconds.

Thanks for any help!

#### EDIT:

Finally I found the largest number Awk could handle on Snow Leopard 10.6.8: `9007199254740992`.

Try this: `echo '9007199254740992' | awk -F ',' '{print $1 + 0}'`

The version of Awk was `20070501` (produced by `awk --version`)

Comment: On which platform are you running? `echo '1318044415123456,1318044415990056' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 - $1 }'` yields `866600` for me.

Comment: Thanks @Johnsyweb. Indeed it works for this case. However, I'm setting this a challenge when exploring Awk. I may use different numbers which a larger than epoch times.

Comment: Can you provide a real example of the problem?

Comment: So far I use to get the difference in epoch time but trying to make as generic as possible to reuse for other cases with larger numbers.

Comment: Premature abstraction is the root of all evil!

Comment: Ok! Got it. I tested on Awk on Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and the largest number it could handle was 9007199254740992. Try this: echo '9007199254740992' | awk -F ',' '{print $1 + 0}'

Comment: 2**53? I guess you have until Tue, 05 Jun 2255 23:47:34 GMT to solve this.

Comment: Yes!!! Btw I found the number manually after a few iterations. I have plenty of time till Tue, 05 Jun 2255 23:47:34 GMT! I am just wondering why they keep 2**53 as the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk script that meets your requirements:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}
{
    s1 = $1
    s2 = $2
    while (length(s1) > 1 && substr(s1, 1, 1) == substr(s2, 1, 1))
    {
        s1 = substr(s1, 2)
        s2 = substr(s2, 2)
    }
    n1 = s1 + 0
    n2 = s2 + 0
    print n2 - n1
}
```